# Integrating MVC code into asp.net forms site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net forms based site, and I am thinking of somehow integrating [OpenForum](http://openforum.codeplex.com/) which is written using MVC. I don't have any experience with MVC, so I'm wondering should I even bother - is it possible/makes sense to build this hybrid?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can add  OpenForum  like a SUBWEBSITE for the your MAINWEBSITE under IIS. It should work well because it is going to have its own BIN folder as well as web.config.

Comment: I thought about this alternative, but I'd really like to keep it as a part of my main site, and a part of the main site's VS project, if possible. The main reason - if it's a separate VS project then I can't share the same master pages/user controls easily.

Comment: I think this is a cheapest way to integrate and support OpenForum together with your main web site.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible. I've done it the other way around - added ASP.NET forms into an MVC site. And it may make sense (I've never used OpenForum), one could migrate to MVC this way.

If you search for "mix mvc and asp.net" there's a few resources with step by step instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can have some working side by side, but you mentioned in a comment about wanting to share master pages and user controls, and that's most likely going to be somewhere between difficult and impossible in some cases.

MVC doesn't use Viewstate which is a big part of webforms, nor does it have the concept of a postback.  It's an entirely different paradigm.  You can share session and also common classes and data structures, but as far as re-using view logic between them, it's most likely not going to be easy.